# Combinatorics on the line segment

Tags: combinatorics

I have a line segment with discrete length $m$ and several shorter line segments with discrete length $n$. The number of  shorter line segments is $k$, with $nk \le m$.

How many ways are there to place these shorter segments on the larger segment? The order of shorter segments is not important, but intervals between any segments (and between segment and ends of larger segment) is important. As an example, the following cases are considered different placements:

$$<---+++-+++-+++->, <--+++--+++--+++>$$

$$<---+++-+++-+++->, <-+++-+++-+++--->$$

Of course all intervals have to be integer. In every placement, all shorter segments have to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider this to be a [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with $k$ bars, where the bars are located at the starting index of the $k$ segments. In the slots in between the bars and at the right of the right-most bar, there must be at least $n-1$ elements. Having selected $k$ out of $m$ elements as the starting index and accounting for these intermediate elements, there are $m - kn$ elements left do distribute among the $k + 1$ slots. The number of possible arrangements thus equals:

$${m - kn + k \choose k}$$

For the given example, where $m=15$, $k=3$ and $n=3$, we find ${9 \choose 3} = 84$.

Comment: m = 15,k=0,n=0 we wille have 16, but correct answer is 1

Comment: @IvanIvanov Corrected! Since there are $k+1$ slots, only $k$ bars need to be selected. For $m = 15$, $k = 0$ and $n = 0$, we now find ${15 \choose 0} = 1$.